# C++: How to implement function in a parent interface with a base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface

Consider following hierarchy:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class SubInterface: public Interface {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class Base: public Interface {
public:
    void foo() {};
};

class Impl: public SubInterface, public Base {
public:
    void bar() {};
};
```

- There are several sub interfaces which offer other methods in addition to foo().
- There can be several implementing classes to a sub interface.
- foo() is always implemented the same way.

Here is an example which simulates how these classes would be used:

```
int main() {
    SubInterface* view1 = new Impl(); // Error! Interface::foo() is pure virtual within Impl
    view1->foo();
    view1->bar();
    Interface* view2 = view1;
    view2->foo();
}
```

Why can't the compiler see that `Interface::foo()` is implemented in `Base` which `Impl` inherits from?

I figured that I could implement `foo()` in `Impl` explicitly and delegate the call to `Base` like this:

```
class Impl: public SubInterface, public Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        Base::foo();
    }
    void bar() {};
};
```

However, I would have to do that for all classes which implement a sub interface, so this way isn't exactly ideal. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Oh, I really wish this was possible.

Comment: @Travis: what do you mean? Of course it's possible...

Comment: @eladidan: It is possible if he can add virtual inheritance to `Base` and `SubInterface`...I suppose it isn't clear in the question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SubInterface` and `Base` should inherit virtually from `Interface` otherwise you are creating ambiguity in form of the [dreaded diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-diamond.html) 
Basically, what happens is that Impl contains two 'instances' of Interface.

Comment: Ah. I had read about the virtual inheritance when trying to solve this but I screwed up by making `Impl` inherit `Interface` virtually. Thanks.

My fancy IDE still thinks that `Impl` is abstract but it works in gcc.

Comment: Actually, it's **virtual inheritance** that creates a diamond. Without virtual inheritance you get a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Here is why - follow the diagram:

[image]

Comment: Can you convert this into ASCII art? My eyes does not let me.